# How to skip for rebasing already pushed commits?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have two branches: `dev` and `edit_order`
On my `dev` branch I have changed one commit `Update library`  (Notice: <<<<<)
Now I am on `edit_order` branch

```
<   ba938ae07 (dev) Merge branch 'edit_order' into dev
|\  
| = 5011ad16b Variable name
| = cfdbf77dd Removed unused code
|/  
< c896d3ba1 Update library                        <<<<<<<<
|
|
| = 719513d75 (HEAD -> edit_order, local/edit_order) Variable name
| > 252bd4580 Update library                      <<<<<<<<
| = 30ce5d1e1 Removed unused code
|/  
o 36fed2d68 (local/dev) Fix link
```

How to rebase `edit_order` onto `dev` branch and ignore already pushed commits `252bd4580 Update library`? (like `git pull --reabase` do)

I expect next result after rebasing:

```
*   ba938ae07 (HEAD -> edit_order, dev) Merge branch 'edit_order' into dev
|\  
| * 5011ad16b Variable name
| * cfdbf77dd Removed unused code
|/  
* c896d3ba1 Update library
* 36fed2d68 (local/dev) Fix link
```

Comment: You must (manually or programmatically) remember which are the pushed commits. The remote-tracking names in your own Git repository come close to doing so, maybe close enough, but actually *using* them this way is potentially tricky (since there may be some on other branches that you'd like your rebase to consider).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm reading your history correctly, but take a look at `git rebase --onto` as it might work for you:

```
$ git branch --show-current
edit_order
$ git rebase --onto dev 252bd4580
```

See `git help rebase` for documentation

Comment: What if `252bd4580` is not first commit? (see updated question)

Comment: Then you find the first commit, you can possible find it with `git merge-base ...` or `git rev-list ...`